# Populating a Combobox with LinqToSql and choose an item from it

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql

Here's code to populate a combobox with Linq-to-SQL:

```
private void FillEmbCB()
{
    DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    var emb = from e in dc.EMBALLAGES
              select new
                     {
                          e.EMB_CODE,
                          e.EMB_LIB
                     };

    Emb1CB.ItemsSource = emb;
    Emb1CB.SelectedValuePath = "EMB_CODE";
    Emb1CB.DisplayMemberPath = "EMB_LIB";

    Emb1CB.SelectedItem = "HOUSSE PROTEC PALETTE"; // Nothing appears in the combobox
    dc.Dispose();
}
```

At the end of that code, I want to choose an item from the combobox I've just populated, and show it in the combobox, but nothing appears, the combobox is always empty.

Here's my Xaml markup:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Emb1CB" Width="200" FontSize="12"
          SelectionChanged="Emb1CB_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SelectedValuePath` is used for data binding (which you should be doing instead of manipulating the GUI directly like this, but that's another discussion). If you want to set SelectedItem yourself then you need to set the value to the parent object that contains the value, e.g.:

```
using System.Linq;

Emb1CB.SelectedItem = emb.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EMB_CODE == "HOUSSE PROTEC PALETTE");
```